# (Scala) generating a sequence that adds 1 to a n digit number

Tags: scala, loops, sequence

how do I generate a sequence of size n that would look like this:

```
n = 3
000
001
002
003
...
010
011
012
...
999
```

I could use fixed number of for loops for a fixed number of digits but how do i do this with n number of digits in a sequence?

Thank you! ^^

Comment: what you mean by "adds 1 to n digit number"? can you show your code as well how you did it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give the output you're looking for but as a `Seq` of `String`. You can replace `3` with `n` to get more or less leading zeros.

`Range(0,1000).map(n => "%03d".format(n))`

`scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(000, 001, 002, 003, 004, 005, 006, 007, 008, 009, 010, 011, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- `n` specifies the number of digits in the number
- The range is from `0 to Math.pow(10, n)`

A dynamic solution would be:

```
val n = 3 //Or any number

def upperBound : Int = Math.pow(10, n).toInt
def formatNum(num : Int) : String = s"%0${n}d".format(num)
def range: Range = Range(0, upperBound)

range.map(formatNum)
```

The main point here being that you can use string interpolation to have variable padding on the numbers using `s"..."`, where variables are denoted by `$var_name` or `${var_name}`